# How converting constructor actually work

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion

I found that a constructor which takes a single argument is called conversion constructor(c++03).But does that mean that particular constructor will create a temporary object implicitly,and assign it to the required object?(which is not visible to us?)Then what is the difference in writing 
  EgClass m=EgClass(1)
     and
  EgClass m=1
Does EgClass(1) typecast int to EgClass?(If so how does this happen?)
Also what happens when we write EgClass m(1)?

Comment: `X x = 1` and `X x=X(1);` are the same, they create a temporary object which may be optimized out. `X x(1);` makes no temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But does that mean that particular constructor will create a temporary object implicitly,and assign it to the required object?

yes, but only formally - in many cases it will optimize those temporaries even when building with optimization turned off. This means that any logging added in constructor, will not indicate that such temporary was created.

> Then what is the difference in writing EgClass m=EgClass(1) and EgClass m=1 Does EgClass(1) typecast int to EgClass?(If so how does this happen?)

`EgClass m=EgClass(1)` it the same as `EgClass m=1`, you can imaging that when compiler see `EgClass m=1` it will transform it to `EgClass m=EgClass(1)` and then to `EgClass m(EgClass(1))`

> Does EgClass(1) typecast int to EgClass?(If so how does this happen?)

yes, 1 is converted to EgClass. This happens using temporary - but again, formally there is a temporary, but compiler is allowed to optimize it out.

> Also what happens when we write EgClass m(1)

integer 1 is converted to object of type EgClass. No temporary is created,even formally.